# How to make diffrenet colour column chart in extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

How to make different color for diffrent bars in extjs i tried to implement with **theme**. But it is not working properly hence i am passing two parameter in **yfield** in series parameter. I am attaching  working example as i am also attaching a sample screenshot for your refrence. Can you please help me to figure it out
**Screenshot**

[image]

You can refer below link for refrence

```
<code> http://jsfiddle.net/sunith_123/f83v0kbb/8/</code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your theme and try the following renderer instead for your chart series:

```
    series: [{
            type: 'column',
            axis: 'left',
            highlight: false,
            xField: 'name',
            yField: ['rocCCI', 'rocCI'],
            renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
                var color = ['orange', 
                             'peachpuff',
                             'green',
                             'greenyellow'][index%4];
                return Ext.apply(attr, {
                    fill: color
                });
            }

        }]
```

You'll get the following result
[image]

The renderer is looping through the 4 colour array (using `index%4` as a key). You can extend this array to add more colours - or make the index calculation more intelligent to choose colours based on the current record rendering.

Only downside is the key colours aren't correct - but they were never going to work with this colour format anyway!